# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, list, function, attributeerror

I was trying bubble sort through define function method but it keeps on showing attribute error. I am not able to understand the reason, so if anyone could explain this error it would be a great help.

```
l=[1,4,7,9,0]

def kono():
    n=len(l)
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range(n-i-1):
            if(l[j]>l[j+1]):
               l[j],l[j+1]=l[j+1],l[j]
b=l.kono()

print(b)
```

Comment: What do you expect `l.kono()` to mean?

Comment: that it will execute that function i created

Comment: That isn't how you call functions in Python -- it is how you call *methods* -- but this definition isn't of a method.

Comment: Change the function definition to `def kono(l)` and the call to `kono(l)`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i tried  chsnging it to kono(l) but it now shows the answer as none

Comment: the expected output is that the list (l) is sorted according to ascending order of its elemnts

Comment: print(b) : None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can add a return. All depends on how you want to define your function

```
l=[1,4,7,9,0]

def kono(l):
    n=len(l)
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range(n-i-1):
            if(l[j]>l[j+1]):
                l[j],l[j+1]=l[j+1],l[j]
    return l

b = kono(l)

print('This is b',b)
#Output: This is b [0, 1, 4, 7, 9]
```

In this case, you will assign the ordered list to `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code so that the function takes a list; then, to call it, use `kono(l)` instead of `l.kono()`; then there's no need to assign the result to `b` since the list is passed as a reference (also the function doesn't return any value):

```
l=[1,4,7,9,0]

def kono(l):
    n=len(l)
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range(n-i-1):
            if(l[j]>l[j+1]):
               l[j],l[j+1]=l[j+1],l[j]
kono(l)

print(l)
```

Comment: ohh so do you mean that when i was calling the result to b the value was not being assigned to it

Comment: There is no `return` statement in your function, so assigning values to it will always result in `None` values. In Python lists (and objects in general) are passed as reference, so changing them inside the function will cause them to also change outside.

Comment: @ altermetax , I write this simple code :def summ(a,b):
    c = a + b
a = 3
b = 5
summ(a,b)
print(a,b) but the output is 3,5

Comment: Numbers are immutable objects, so you do need to return those if you need the value.